# Given two timestamps, calculate the number of elapsed working hours between these dates

Tags: google-bigquery

Given two timestamps in a table `start_time, end_time` calculate the total elapsed working hours that occur between them.

Working hours are defined in a separate table(s) of your choosing.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was down voted. Can someone help me understand why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.working_hours` AS (
  SELECT 1 weekday, 'Sun' DAY, NULL start_time, NULL end_time UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Mon', TIME(9, 0, 0), TIME(17, 0, 0) UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Tue', TIME(9, 0, 0), TIME(17, 0, 0) UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'Wed', TIME(9, 0, 0), TIME(17, 0, 0) UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'Thu', TIME(9, 0, 0), TIME(17, 0, 0) UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'Fri', TIME(9, 0, 0), TIME(17, 0, 0) UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'Sat', TIME(9, 0, 0), TIME(15, 0, 0) 
), `project.dataset.availability` AS (
  SELECT 'Tom' name, TIMESTAMP '2018-01-10 12:38:04' start_time, TIMESTAMP '2018-02-11 10:38:04' end_time UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mike', TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 12:35:00', TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 14:35:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Sam', TIMESTAMP '2018-01-06 12:35:00', TIMESTAMP '2018-01-07 14:35:00' 
), full_days_minutes AS (
  SELECT name, 
    SUM(TIME_DIFF(h.end_time, h.start_time, MINUTE)) minutes
  FROM `project.dataset.availability` a, 
    UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE(start_time), DATE(end_time))) DAY
  JOIN `project.dataset.working_hours` h
    ON h.weekday = EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM DAY)
  GROUP BY name
), corrections AS (
  SELECT name,
    IFNULL(CASE -- correction for start time 
      WHEN TIME(a.start_time) > x.end_time THEN TIME_DIFF(x.end_time, x.start_time, MINUTE)
      WHEN TIME(a.start_time) < x.start_time THEN 0
      ELSE TIME_DIFF(TIME(a.start_time), x.start_time, MINUTE)
    END, 0) + 
    IFNULL(CASE -- correction for end time 
      WHEN TIME(a.end_time) < y.start_time THEN TIME_DIFF(y.end_time, y.start_time, MINUTE)
      WHEN TIME(a.end_time) > y.end_time THEN 0
      ELSE TIME_DIFF(y.end_time, TIME(a.end_time), MINUTE)
    END, 0)
    AS correction
  FROM  `project.dataset.availability` a
  JOIN `project.dataset.working_hours` x ON x.weekday = EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM a.start_time)
  JOIN `project.dataset.working_hours` y ON y.weekday = EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM a.end_time)
)
SELECT name, minutes - correction AS elapsed_minutes, 
  ROUND((minutes - correction) / 60, 2) elapsed_hours
FROM full_days_minutes JOIN corrections USING(name)
```

with result as

```sql
Row name    elapsed_minutes elapsed_hours    
1   Tom              12,622        210.37    
2   Mike                120          2   
3   Sam                 145          2.42
```

Note: code assumes that start_time <= end_time in availability and working_hours tables

Comment: if answer helped  - please consider voting up :o)

Comment: Mr BigQuery strikes again ;)

Comment: Excellent query! It seems to me that if you have multiple "Names" with the same value you'll get wrong results for fairly obvious reasons. This is a non-issue in this case, but for me, as I adapted it for my own use case I had to pay attention to that.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have a working hours table, here is a solution in Snowflake SQL:

```
select
  t.id
  , sum(datediff(‘second’, 
               -- calculate the max of the two start time
               (case when t.start <= 
                          w.working_day_start_timestamp
                     then w.working_day_start_timestamp
                     else t.start
                end),
               -- calculate the min of the two end times
               (case when t.end >= 
                          w.working_day_end_timestamp
                     then w.working_day_end_timestamp
                     else t.end 
                end)
               )) / 3600 -- convert to hourly
  as working_hour_diff
from 
  working_days_times w,
  cross join time_intervals t
where -- select all intersecting intervals
  (
   t.start <= w.working_day_end_timestamp
   and
   t.end >= w.working_day_start_timestamp
  )
and -- select only working days
  w.is_working_day
group by
  t.id
```

Here is an article with more detail implementing this both in SQL and as a Javascript UDF in Snowflake:

https://medium.com/dandy-engineering-blog/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-working-hours-between-two-timestamps-in-sql-b5696de66e51